# How could I prototype a board game with a variety of units using abstract icons?

Tags: game-design, dice, prototyping, rorys-story-cubes

I'm pretty fuzzy in terms of what board game I want to create, and I often find myself using normal dice for the units, which is often messy and confusing (were 1s or 2s archers? Whose mage was die 5?).

I saw some Story cubes having arrows and fireballs and skulls on them, so they could prove useful as multifunctional tokens for generating ideas and interactions.

Could you recommend me a particular set or an alternative to them?

Comment: Any reason for story cubes specifically? For prototyping they are probaly _very_ expensive, especially compared to just using cardboard tokens or something.

Comment: Not an answer (as they are not story cubes) but you could grab some wooden cubes a la https://www.walmart.com/ip/75-Wood-Craft-Blocks-Natural-Wooden-Unfinished-Hardwood-Blocks-Square-0-6-Cubes/383569558 and put whatever you want on them

Comment: @J.Fox I think that might be the best solution, it solves the underlying issue (clearly identifying what a die's side means for prototyping). Might be worth a full answer.

Comment: @Malco If you think it's worth a full answer I'll write something up.

Comment: @J.Fox I have recommended the Asker edit the question to make it a bit more clear what their underlying issue is. Your answer will probably become more relevant if they make the edit, but it might be something to keep an eye on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using story cubes (which as noted are probably going to run you a fair chunk in bulk and aren't necessarily customizable), you might be better off just picking up some blank wooden cubes such as the ones found [here](https://www.walmart.com/ip/75-Wood-Craft-Blocks-Natural-Wooden-Unfinished-Hardwood-Blocks-Square-0-6-Cubes/383569558) or [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XV13944).

[image]

Probably a lot cheaper, and you can put whatever you'd like on them instead of having to settle for what's on the story cubes. You could also have some stickers printed, for example at Game Crafter you can upload designs and have them printed onto half-inch stickers: see [here](https://www.thegamecrafter.com/parts/blank-dice-stickers).

Note that I personally have not used Game Crafter's stickers so I can't vouch for the quality, but I've gotten the cubes from Amazon before and they are pretty nice.

Comment: Yeah, this'd work for me. I see how what I asked was an XY problem-thing.

Comment: Just as a continuation - Lords of Waterdeep uses orange cubes like the ones in the image to represent warriors, white cubes to represent priests, etc.

Comment: You can get a pack of 500 colored, 1cm cubes for like $12 on Amazon.  You get 10 colors, 50 cubes of each.... looks like the price is currently up to $17, still much cheaper than the wood cubes.